# According to the given recursive function, are these words in L?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Let $\sum = \{0, 1\}$. Define $L$ and $L^{'}$ recursively as follows:

- $\lambda \in L$
- if $w \in L$ then $0w \in L$ and $1w \in L^{'}$
- if $w \in L^{'}$ then $0w \in L^{'}$ and $1w \in L$

$\lambda$ is the empty word. And $w$ is a given word.

Are the following words in $L: 0010, 1001, 1110, 0011, 1111, 0000?$

---

I know the answer is any word that has an even number of $1$s in it is in $L$. But I don't know how to go about determining this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes but IDK if what I'm doing is correct. I'm not sure how to start. Should I start by assuming the given word is $\in L$? So if $0010$ is the word, and it's $\in L$ then I have two branches, $0w \in L$ and $1w \in L^{'}$. What next? And does $0w$ in this case mean $00010$? Am I concatenating bits at the beginning?

Comment: Have you considered induction?

Comment: The inductive hypothesis $S_n$ is that strings length $n$ are in $L$ if they contain an even number of 1s, and in $L'$ if they contain an odd number of 1s.

Comment: Try imagining an infinite binary tree. The root is the empty word. Any downwards path on your tree defines a valid word. Going to the left child is prefixing a 0, going to the right child is prefixing a 1. Which branches are cut off by your rules (ie, which paths are inaccessible, which words are not part of your language) ? The tricky thing here is to compare two such binary trees.

Comment: Not great with induction but the binary tree analogy helps. I can now see why the words with even number of $1$s are in $L$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will try and correctly phrase this solution as an induction problem.
We claim that each word with an even number of $1$s is in $L$ and each word with an odd number of $1$s is in $L'$.
To this end, first note that the recursive problem is deterministic and given any word in $0$s and $1$s, we can follow the procedure and find out that it belongs to a set, and only one.

We make an induction on the length ot the words.

We consider as base case $n=0$: the only word, the empty word, has an even $(0)$ number of $1s$ and lies in $L$.

Now, suppose that for some $n \geqslant 0$ the induction hypotheses holds for all words of length $n$.
We show that it's also true for $n+1$, which completes the proof.

Let $w$ be a word of length $n+1$.
We consider four cases:

- $w$ has an even number of $1$s and ends in $1$, say it's $w = 1v$.
  Then $v$ has an odd number of $1$s and length $n$, so by the induction hypothesis $v\in L'$.
  It follows from the recurrence relations $w$ must lie in $L$, which agrees with our induction hypothesis.
- $w$ has an even number of $1$s and ends in $0$, say it's $w = 0v$.
  Then $v$ has an even number of $1$s and length $n$, so by the induction hypothesis $v\in L$.
  It follows from the recurrence relations $w$ must lie in $L$, which agrees with our induction hypothesis.
- $w$ has an odd number of $1$s and ends in $1$, say it's $w = 1v$.
  Then $v$ has an even number of $1$s and length $n$, so by the induction hypothesis $v\in L$.
  It follows from the recurrence relations $w$ must lie in $L'$, which agrees with our induction hypothesis.
- $w$ has an odd number of $1$s and ends in $0$, say it's $w = 0v$.
  Then $v$ has an odd number of $1$s and length $n$, so by the induction hypothesis $v\in L'$.
  It follows from the recurrence relations $w$ must lie in $L'$, which agrees with our induction hypothesis.

This covers all cases and completes the induction.

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to translate your question in terms of grammars. The language $L$ is generated by the grammar
\begin{align}
 S &\to 0S + 1T + \lambda \\
 T &\to 0T + 1S
\end{align}
Thus $L$ is the first component of the least solution $(S,T)$ of the system of equations in languages
\begin{align}
 S &= 0S + 1T + \lambda \\
 T &= 0T + 1S
\end{align}
Using [Arden's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_rule), the second equation gives $T = 0^*1S$. The first equation now becomes $S = 0S + 10^*1S + \lambda = (0 + 10^*1)S + \lambda$. Applying again Arden's rule, one gets $S = (0 + 10^*1)^*$, which is exactly the set of words containing an even number of occurrences of $1$'s.